# c++ Delete a list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, qt, pointers

I have this class-object in c++ (using Qt):

```
class Foo {

    public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();

        QList<Bar*> barList;
}
```

My question is: do I need to delete every Bar object in the barList in the destructor (for loop), or since the list is a static object everything will be deleted with the Foo object ?

Thank you.

Comment: The resources pointed to by the `Bar*`s will likely not be cleaned up when that `barlist` is destroyed.

Comment: _"or since the list is a static object"_ What makes you think so?

Comment: By static I mean that the list has not been instantiated using a `new`, correct me if I'm wrong but a non pointer variable in an object is always destroyed with the object right ?

Comment: `static != on the stack` (read my post below :)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `qDeleteAll(...)` (which is basically a `foreach` over your list and calling `delete` on every item inside). Do **not** use `QList::clear()` which simply removes the items from the list but doesn't trigger deallocation. You can however combine the two to first release the memory of the objects your list items (pointers) are referencing and then use `clear()` to remove the items (pointers) themselves from the list leaving you with an empty `barList`.

In addition to that if `Bar` is derived from `QObject` you can just set its parent to another object/widget which you are sure will be properly released at some point. This is the parent-child model in Qt and is a nice way to clean stuff without the need to take care of the deletion yourself.

Also `static` here is incorrect. I think you mean `on the stack` that is your `barList` is not dynamically allocated.

**A word of caution:** even though you have `Bar*` this does **not** mean that the items themselves are dynamically allocated. You can have items created on the stack and then append them by reference to your least which in terms will lead to segmentation fault if you try to delete them. Since you don't provide more code I can't say if your `Bar*`s are dynamically allocated or not.

Of course it really depends on what `Bar` represents so the second suggestion might not be proper for the given scenario.

Btw your question shows a general lack of understanding how pointers work and is in fact not Qt related (even though your problem here is in the context of Qt). My suggestion for you would be to look up some general information on pointers in C/C++ and then move onto the containers provided by Qt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm definitely going to find more informations on pointers, I've used PyQt a lot and this is happening under the sheets.

Comment: The Bar class is a Coordinate object that has only two int on the stack, and I am dynamically allocating them, thanks again.

Comment: While you can use PyQt without really having done any C++ Qt code I would suggest not to go down that road. While PyQt is really nice (Python after all :P), there is still the C++ code that lies underneath since PyQt is just a wrapper. Your Python code might look alright but then you suddenly get a segmentation fault...Why? Because the C++ code underneath broke. :P Also there are thing that are not available in PyQt such as the concurrency module which is completely template based and makes it not possible to create a wrapper in Python. So yeah, it's worth learning both. :)

Comment: If you just want to store two `int`s I would go with a structure or an array instead of a whole bloated class to be honest.

Comment: The choice of a class for my coordinates is because I can then create specific method, the idea was to make my own `Vector2`class, but thanks for the feedback :)
I've begin to learn C++ because I've heard that python is a lot less efficient since it's not compiled, what's your opinion on this ?

Comment: The same applies when learning any language - don't start by using a specific framework. Learn the basics and then go for Qt or whatever. Otherwise there is the problem of 1)facing some problems that are due to the complexity of the framework and 2)you may think (because of your experience with the framework) that feature X found in the framework is universal. Alone the containers in Qt have many important differences to the STL containers so that's that.

Comment: Python is quite efficient (especially when using the Cython interpreter) so it might be enough for you though it never hurts to know more than one programming language plus the fact that in case of PyQt you have to cash in if you develop a commercial product (unlike C++ Qt which with the exception of a couple of its modules and static linking can be used without paying any royalties).